# Query Active Directory Fast

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Let's say I have a list of SID.

Currently I'm querying the AD for each SID. Something like

```
foreach(string sidString in listOfSid)
{
    DirectorySearcher search = new ....

    search.Filter = string.Format("(objectSid={0})", ConvertToOctetString(sidString));

    var result = search.FindOne();

    .....
}
```

Is there a faster way than this? Instead of looping is there a way to query all informations in one shot instead of the loop?

Comment: Does it have to be done in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but why don't you build a filter in a loop and then search one time. The filter will look like :

```
(|(objectSid=sid1)(objectSid=sid2)(...)(objectSid=sidn))
```

If you've got .NET 3.5 or higher, then you can [work with principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx).

According to [How Active Directory Searches Work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755809%28WS.10%29.aspx), the maximum LDAP request size that the server attempts to process is 10485760 bytes. If the server receives a request that is larger than this value, it closes the connection. Having said that, I never tested it.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly it! I wasn't sure how the syntax for the filter was. Now I understand it.

Comment: Yes a bit strange it use Polish notation (PN) or Prefic Notation which are mathematicals notation wherein every operator prefix all of its operands.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge! I was wondering which syntax this was.

Comment: is there a limit to the length of the filter? I need the same functionality, and there could be hundreds of SIDs.

Comment: @GarethOwen, I edit my answer to ake into aacounr your comment.